# Regression Coefficients

Tags: regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients, sample

I am performing regression analysis based on a full sample and two sub samples from the full sample. Is it always the case that the coefficient of the full sample lies between the coefficients of the two sub samples?

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, 
please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: No, it is actually an empirical study i am conducting for my boss and he is making the claim that the coefficient of full sample should always fall between two sub samples which i find it awkward. I know the mean of the variables of the full sample should always between the two sub samples but i am not sure of coefficients

Comment: Are the means, or the coefficients, between the 2 in your case?  What do you mean by "sub sample"?  Is this a partition of the full sample into only 2 sets?  Can the same datum end up in both subsamples, eg?  Could there be data that exist in neither?

Comment: Regardless of the details, the answer is a definite, resounding no.  By inspection, or even random selection, you should have no difficulties finding small subsamples of your data whose range of coefficients does not cover the coefficients from the full dataset.

Comment: By sub sample, i have data on full sample of 300 offers and i have sub sample of offers with toeholds above 50% and toeholds below 50% based on the 300 offers. Yes, the means of the full sample (ie 300 offers) lies between the mean of the two sub samples but the coefficient does not